# WxSocket (Was not declared in this scope)

Tags: wxwidgets

**Hello, if i try to build this code here, ill get a error and dont know what to do.**

```
void wxsocket_test_finalFrame::OnServerStart(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
// Create the address - defaults to localhost:0 initially
wxIPV4address addr;
addr.Service(3000);
// Create the socket. We maintain a class pointer so we can
// shut it down
m_server = new wxSocketServer(addr);
// We use Ok() here to see if the server is really listening
if (! m_server->Ok())
{
return;
}

// Set up the event handler and subscribe to connection events
m_server->SetEventHandler(*this, SERVER_ID);
m_server->SetNotify(wxSOCKET_CONNECTION_FLAG);
m_server->Notify(true);
}
void wxsocket_test_finalFrame::OnServerEvent(wxSocketEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
// Accept the new connection and get the socket pointer
wxSocketBase* sock = m_server->Accept(false);
// Tell the new socket how and where to process its events
sock->SetEventHandler(*this, SOCKET_ID);
sock->SetNotify(wxSOCKET_INPUT_FLAG | wxSOCKET_LOST_FLAG);
sock->Notify(true);
}
void wxsocket_test_finalFrame::OnSocketEvent(wxSocketEvent& event)
{
wxSocketBase *sock = event.GetSocket();
// Process the event
switch(event.GetSocketEvent())
{
case wxSOCKET_INPUT:
{
char buf[10];
// Read the data
sock->Read(buf, sizeof(buf));
// Write it back
sock->Write(buf, sizeof(buf));
// We are done with the socket, destroy it
sock->Destroy();
break;
}
case wxSOCKET_LOST:
{
sock->Destroy();
break;
}
}
}
```

**\wxsocket_test_finalMain.cpp|99|error: 'm_server' was not declared in this scope|**

**OS:       Windows**

**Compiler: gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)**

im a bloody newbie and cant figure out what is happening here, someone has a clue ?

Comment: you didn't mention what OS/compiler you are using.

Comment: Im so sorry

gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

Comment: Which command do you use to compile your code? Also, please put the whole code - it is missing preprocessor part. And look at the socket sample provided by wxWidgets for details.

Comment: i dont use any commands, ill just press a button

Comment: which button? Are you using an IDE? Which one? And did you include all necessary headers by looking at the sample?

Comment: we already resloved the problem. we just needed to link the net libary :)

Comment: yes, but the error as it appears in you question comes from the compiler, not a linker. ;-) You need to be careful and explain exactly what the problem you are trying to solve.